# Возвращается url из базы данных, но сервер Django не находит media фаил

Tags: html, python, django

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой. На HTML странице не отображается картинка потому что адрес url не правильный.
Вот код settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y9xx15%xyrs$%utkpa)7sbm!zr&g5te&cfz_(h^$=uz&jla2b_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #Plugins
    'markdown',
    #myapps
    'display'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'Ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static_in_pro/out_static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_pro","static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro","out_static"),

]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media_in_pro/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_in_pro","media_root")
```

Вот и urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name=admin),
    url(r'^',include('display.urls', namespace='space_display')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Вот html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for project in Projects %}
    <div class="row" style="height:20%; border:4px solid yellow">
         <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <span><img src="{{ project.main_img.url }}" alt=""></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4" style="color:#33cccc;">

               {{project.project_name}}
               {{project.stage}}
               {{project.date_begin}}
               {{project.date_end}} <br>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>       
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

И вот ошибка

```
 GET http://192.168.1.10:8000/media_in_pro/projects/2016/09/27/project1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Для начала исправьте последнюю строчку вашего `urls.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Nikmoon!
Исправил!

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй вставить эту строку в массив urlpatterns в главном urls.py

```
url(r'^media_in_pro/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
```

Comment: Да есть у него строчка нужная, просто в ней ошибка.